# How to setup a dynamo db trigger in AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am new to AWS lambda and have a doubt in mind. I have a dynamodb table(**"People"**) and in that table I have one attribute called **"SeniorCitizen"**. By default the attribute is set to Yes/No based on another attribute **"Age"**.

At some point of time **Age** attribute gets updated on the table and based on that I want my lambda function to be triggered to update the **SeniorCitizen** attribute value from No to Yes if Age gets passed 60 for a particular person.

So how can I set my trigger to check the age in the table when the table gets updated and trigger my lambda function to perform the actual update of **SeniorCitizen** attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Once you configure DynamoDB to trigger a Lambda function, it will trigger the function on every record update. There is no way to tell DynamoDB to only trigger the Lambda function when a specific field is updated.

You simply need to configure the Lambda function to check if `Age` and `SeniorCitizen` values do not match, and have it perform an update to the DynamoDB record if not, using the AWS SDK for the programming language your Lambda function is written in.

Comment: Is there any way to know which items were updated in my lambda function? Because when the table gets updated, I need the record which got updated in order to check the modified Age of the person and decide whether to change SeniorCitizen or not

Comment: The information about the item that got updates is part of the event data passed to the Lambda function. Otherwise, the whole DynamoDB trigger feature would be pointless. I recommend reading the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html